# Redis works on console, but fails in application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis, redistogo

I'm using Redis with `split` gem in a RoR application hosted on Heroku.

I've configured it with RedisToGo using the following codes:

**/config/initializers/redis.rb**

```
uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"] || "redis://localhost:6379/" )
REDIS = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)
```

**/config/application.rb**

```
config.gem 'redis'
```

When I try to

```
REDIS.set("foo","bar")
```

on Heroku console, it works fine. It shows Redis ToGo address.

However, when I try to load the application I get the following error:

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - Unable to connect to Redis on localhost:6379
```

Howcome `REDIS` is responding correctly, with correct address in Heroku console, but it shows localhost address when the application calls it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it, and I'll let the solution registered:

I wasn't initializing `Split.redis`, and therefore it was trying to create a default `Redis`, which has localhost as host.

So I created the following initializer

**/config/initializers/split.rb**

```
Split.redis = REDIS
```

and then Split could find it!